# Google speech long_running_recognizer does not work when fired through celery task

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, google-cloud-platform

The code below works when fired as a script using python. But the same, when i encapsulate in a celery task and try to execute, it does not work. The celery task prints the line before the long_running_recognize, but does not print the one after the operation - seems like it gets stuck at the long_running_recognize call when executing as a celery task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import speech_recognition as sr
import json

import sqlalchemy

import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

audio=speech.types.RecognitionAudio(uri='gs://<bucket_name>/<audio_file>')

config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    language_code='en-US')

print('FIRING GOOGLE SPEECH RECOGNITION')

# Detects speech in the audio file
operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
response = operation.result(timeout=600)

outfile = open('test.txt', 'w')

for result in response.results:
    for alternative in result.alternatives:
        print('=' * 20)
        outfile.write('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
        outfile.write('=' * 20)
        outfile.write("Confidence: {}".format(alternative.confidence))
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
        print(alternative.confidence)

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Hey were u able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, but it worked recently. I rolled back to these requirements in pip and it solved the problem.

```
google-api-python-client==1.6.4
google-auth==1.1.1
google-cloud-core==0.27.1
google-cloud-speech==0.29.0
google-gax==0.15.15
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.2
```